# Laravel admin login with access levels using filters before and after?

Tags: php, laravel

So I have to have one login surface, and after the login I have to decide which admin surface is available for the user.

So I set up routing for that, before one can access the admin page, they need to login and after they logged in they are redirected to the corresponding admin page:

```
Route::get('admin', array('before' => 'auth', 'after' => 'access_lvl'));
Route::get('admin1', array('before' => 'auth', 'as'=>"admin1", 'uses' => 'admin1@index'));
Route::get('admin2', array('before' => 'auth', 'as'=>"admin2", 'uses' => 'admin2@index'));
Route::get('admin3', array('before' => 'auth', 'as'=>"admin3", 'uses' => 'admin3@index'));
```

and here is the `access_lvl` filter:

```
Route::filter('access_lvl',function(){
  $access_lvl=Auth::user()->access_lvl;
  var_dump($access_lvl);
  switch($access_lvl){
    case 1: return Redirect::to('admin1/'); break;
    case 2: return Redirect::to('admin2/'); break;
    case 3: return Redirect::to('admin3/'); break;
    default: return Redirect::to('admin3/'); break;
  };
});
```

Unfortunately I get an Trying to get property of non-object error on `Auth::user()->access_lvl;` in chrome and no errors just a int(1) response in firefox. Can you help me on this problem please? Where am I making a mistake? Is this before, after logic correct? Or should I add the after filter somewhere else?

Also I am using Laravel3 I think. I just got this project, which I have to carry on.

Comment: You're probably not logged in in Chrome so `Auth::user()` doesn't return an object. In Firefox, you're logged in but `var_dump($access_level)` sends response to the browser which prevents the redirect working as headers can't be sent after data has been sent.

Comment: @Swinburne but do you think the logic is correct?

Comment: I suppose this wont work if as when I log out from firefox it wont log back in and i will get the same error as on chrome

Comment: You'd need to check the user is logged in as part of the filter. If they're not logged in, redirect to the login page. If they are, then run the switch statement. Or run another filter first which checks the user is logged in first.

Comment: @BenSwinburne but the before filter is there to log the user in, and check that too, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have a solution:

The `auth` filter redirects you to the `login` surface if `Auth::guest()` is true, so it can redirect you to the corresponding admin pages via the `switch` statement like this:

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::to('admin/login');
    $access_lvl=Auth::user()->access_lvl;
    switch($access_lvl){
      case 1: return Redirect::to('admin1/'); break;
      case 2: return Redirect::to('admin2/'); break;
      case 3: return Redirect::to('admin3/'); break;
      default: return Redirect::to('admin3/'); break;
    };
});
```

This means you don't have to have a separate `access_lvl` filter

**Although this is a solution I still have questions:**

What's the probem with the `after` filter in the original case? 
When should I use the `after` filter?

Comment: After happens after the response has been sent to the browser. The redirect function uses `header('Location: admin1/');` but headers cannot be sent after the response has been sent. See [the header manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Answer (score -1):

You should use [Laravel Middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware)

This is how to avoid `switch() {case:}` in your routes

Comment: OP is using Laravel 3 (or possibly 4) which doesn't have a middleware stack.